# how to customize showsCameraControls in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

How to customize the controls over the camera in iphone using programming?
As there are two modes in camera, one is for taking photo and second in for recording movie, simply I want a view that does not have any recording control, and have some else option in that
How can I do that?
Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
picker.cameraOverlayView = someView;
```

Where someView is your custom UIView in which you design your own camera UI. [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) class reference is a good place to get you started.

Comment: ok, means I have to make a custom view that contains two buttons, but how do I change in between them, means from camera mode to other mode of app instead of recording?

Comment: I read the documentations, but just I want one more answer that how to switch between modes in camera, same as build-in iphone app for camera is switching between camera and recording, I want to switch with camera and my own mode of camera that capture serveral pictures

Comment: You should post that as a second question as it's entirely different thing. And you should really improve your accept-rate if you want a quality answer to such a question.

Comment: OK, I am asking an second question, let me write it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020475/how-to-use-switch-between-different-modes-in-uiimagepickercontrollers-custom-con

Comment: Check link and try to help me

Comment: How about you describe your question better and improve your accept-rate by accepting answers to your previous questions first? Like this one.

Comment: I liked and upvoted, but yet am confused regarding the actual query, I want two modes and want to switch between them, please help me out