# How to use switch between different modes in UIImagePickerController's custom controls?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

```
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
picker.cameraOverlayView = someView;
```

As I will add some custom view to showCameraControls, then how can I switch in between modes, like native app of iphone switches between camera and recording, same as I want to switch between camera and one more camera having button on it, how can I do it?
Help !

Comment: So just to get clear here, you want to create a custom mode for your camera? What do you want this custom mode to do exactly?

Comment: I want two modes, one for taking image and save to album, seconds take some snaps and make series of images on clicking save button,

Comment: The only difference in this app is that instead of having a sliding switch that allows you to go back and forth between video and photo mode, you can swap between photo and blast.  No video. When the blast mode is selected, the app will take multiple pictures on one press of the button e.g. 3-4 in a second. The app shouldn’t slow down therefore it should be allocated extra resources to handle the load of burst mode.

Comment: Ok I understand what you want to do now. Going to write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project shows you how to make your own custom overlay for the UIImagePickerController, and how to use it. For more info on what each of the properties and methods do for the UIImagePickerController, refer [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html). Hope that helps!

Comment: Let me read it, can you guide me with some code or structure, and should I inherit the UIImagePickerController, or just use it?

Comment: I would download the sample project and play with it. It basically has all the code you'll need to use the UIImagePickerController. You can get deeper into the camera by looking at AVCaptureSessions, but that is much more work, and most likely more control them you'll need to have.

Answer (score 1):

In your custom view, you will have one button setup with the picker as target and it's takePicture method. Then you would have another button, or switch, or however you want to go to your custom mode, and there you would have one button to start/stop snapping. This button should have self for target (self as the view controller that you presented the picker from) and a custom toggleSnapping method. You also need to set yourself as a delegate to image picker to get notified when each picture is taken. Oh, and a BOOL instance variable that tracks if snapping is currently active or not. Then your toggleSnapping method could look something like this:

```
- (void)toggleSnapping
{
    isSnapping = !isSnapping; // (this will reverse NO to YES and vice-versa)
    [picker takePicture]; // starts taking 1st picture, delegate will take care of rest
    if (isSnapping) {
        // configure your button to show stop icon
    } else {
        // configure your button to show start snapping icon
    }
}
```

And you would need to implement picker's delegate method in which you simply start another picture if isSnapping is currently YES:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // save the snapped picture to the camera roll

    if (isSnapping) { // if burst mode is on, take another picture
        [picker takePicture];
    }
}
```